# I cannot get xts to recognize Time Series in rownames

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I am having a problem with the xts package. I am trying to create an xts from a dataframe. For simplicity sake, I tried to replicate what I am trying to do on a small df below:

```
> df <- japanTOPIX[,1, drop = FALSE]
> typeof(df[,1])
[1] "double"
> typeof(rownames(df))
[1] "character"
> head(df, 3)
           X7164.JT.Equity
12/27/2000            65.0
12/28/2000            66.5
12/29/2000            66.2
> head(as.Date(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),3)
[1] "2000-12-27" "2000-12-28" "2000-12-29"
> timeBased(as.Date(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] TRUE
> xts(df, by = as.Date(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
Error in xts(df, by = as.Date(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y")) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
> head(strptime(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),3)
[1] "2000-12-27 EST" "2000-12-28 EST" "2000-12-29 EST"
> timeBased(strptime(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] TRUE
> xts(df, by = strptime(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
Error in xts(df, by = strptime(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y")) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
> head(as.POSIXlt(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),3)
[1] "2000-12-27 EST" "2000-12-28 EST" "2000-12-29 EST"
> timeBased(as.POSIXlt(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] TRUE
> xts(df, by = as.POSIXlt(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
Error in xts(df, by = as.POSIXlt(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y")) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
> head(as.POSIXct(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),3)
[1] "2000-12-27 EST" "2000-12-28 EST" "2000-12-29 EST"
> timeBased(as.POSIXct(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
[1] TRUE
> xts(df, by = as.POSIXct(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
Error in xts(df, by = as.POSIXct(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y")) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

As you can see, I am getting an error in every attempt of trying to create this xts. The package claims I am not ordering by a time based object, but the 'by = ' variable is, in fact, time based. Any help??
(Please let me know if the example or code is not clear, and I will try to clarify.)

EDIT: I thought this may have to do with some non-unique values in the rownames, but that is not the case:

```
> nrow(df)
[1] 5115
> length(unique(rownames(df)))
[1] 5115
```

Comment: Wrong format string. Use '-' ... Or nothing.

Comment: @BondedDust Hi Bonded. His data is of the form `12/27/2000 ` as you can see in `head(df, 3)`. Using `-` will produce `<NA>`s if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `xts` function incorrectly. The second argument is supposed to be `order.by` and not `by`. See the following example with your data:

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text='
           X7164.JT.Equity
12/27/2000            65.0
12/28/2000            66.5
12/29/2000            66.2')
```

Solution:

```
> xts(df, order.by = as.Date(rownames(df), format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
           X7164.JT.Equity
2000-12-27            65.0
2000-12-28            66.5
2000-12-29            66.2
```

And as you can see it works as intended!

P.S. instead of `as.Date` you can also use `as.POSIXct` or `as.POSIXlt` or `strptime`. All of them work correctly!

Comment: Wow. Every time. I am an idiot. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Don't worry about it. It has happened to all of us plenty of times :P. We all need some help from time to time debugging. Glad I could be of help :)